# Flutter social inlogning with Wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, flutter

I face a problem.
I want to use social loggning to my Flutter APP which is connected to Wordpress backend, so the users can login with google for exemple and this logning save on the backend wordpress.

Is there any one can help me with that?